# Device finger print not getting recorded in Jmeter script

Tags: javascript, jmeter, performance-testing, sha256, credit-card

I face error while scripting Credit card transaction in jmeter.
Issue seems device finger print is not getting capture (which is dynamic ) .this dynamic parameter is not generated hence script fails .signature generation algorithm generates signature but jmeter fail to capture it .

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if your fingerprint checking or signature generation algos rely on JavaScript execution in the client (browser) you won't be able to record and replay your scenario in JMeter.

The options are in:

1. Use a real browser, there is [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework, this way each thread (virtual user) will kick off a real browser and real browsers are normally capable of executing JavaScript
2. Replicate the logic of JavaScript in terms of fingerprint reporting or signature generation using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T for your valuable answer. let me check other option as mentioned